# PHP: POST Content-Length Warning

Tags: php, post, warnings, content-length

When I try to post some data that exceeds the php.ini post_max_size setting I get this error:

Warning:  Unknown: POST Content-Length of X bytes exceeds the limit of Y bytes in  on line 0.

I don't want to increase the post_max_size, I just want to be able to turn off the warning and tell if the post data exceeds the post_max_size. I've tried to turn of the warnings with error_reporting but since the warning is on line 0 that doesn't help.

Comment: use display_errors = Off

Comment: Options that affect things that happen before the script starts can only be changed in php.ini, not in the script itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your php.ini and set `error_reporting` to the production value that is in the comments. Set `display_errors` to `Off`. That should be enough. Remember to log errors to a log file.

Comment: Actually, you don't have to set `display_errors` to `Off`, you only have to set `display_startup_errors` to `Off`.